# Traveling to France and reentering Germany under a Schengen visa if I have a Fiktionsbescheinigung

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, france

I am planning a short, tourism trip from Germany to France, entirely by train.

I have a Brazilian passport, thus in general I do not need to apply to Schengen visas beforehand, since it can be issued directly on arrival at any Schengen area country.

Currently, I legally live and work in Germany under a work visa. However, one week before my travel date, my working visa will expire. By then, I will be waiting for my residence permit, hence I will only have a Fiktionsbescheinigung. This is a provisional residence permit, but it does not allow me to leave and reenter Germany.

Given that I have never had a tourist visa (meaning I comply with the 90/180 tourism stays in Schengen area contries), would I be able to enter France/reenter Germany as a tourist?

Relatedly, I am also concerned about the travel taking place by train. Since, as far as I know, passport checks are not common when traveling between Schengen countries, what would happen in case no one checks my passport and issues me a tourism visa at the French border, but I later get checked when reentering Germany?

Timeline:

- Arrived in Germany with a work visa (never had a tourism visa.)
- Will have stayed for 6 months.
- Visa will be expired and I will have a Fiktionsbescheinigung.
- Plan to travel from Germany to France by train for tourism, then back.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79644/entering-germany-with-a-fiktionsbescheinigung and also maybe https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169851/traveling-with-erlaubnisfiktion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a Brazilian passport, thus in general I do not need to apply to Schengen visas beforehand,...

A **Fiktionsbescheinigung** is not valid for travel to other Schengen Countries when it contains the text **Gilt nicht für Auslandsreisen** (Not valid for for trips abroad).

This will not be the case for persons who do not require a Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area.

> would I be able to enter France/reenter Germany as a tourist?

Yes, if the Fiktionsbescheinigung does not contain the **Gilt nicht für Auslandsreisen** text, which should be the case since Brazil is listed in Annex II and therefore no Schengen Visa is required

- check this when you receive the Fiktionsbescheinigung!

> what would happen in case no one checks my passport and issues me a tourism visa at the French border, but I later get checked when reentering Germany?

(I assume with **tourism visa** you mean entry stamp)

An entry stamp is only given at the **external** Schengen Area borders (the French/German border is an **internal** Schengen Area border).

A residence permit card/D-Visa/valid Fiktionsbescheinigung will explain the reason why you have no current entry stamp should you be checked at some point and allows you to return to Germany.

---

See my answer that quotes the relevant portion of **General Administrative Provisions for the Residence Act** section 81.3.6 (page 335) that list the cases where such a text should **not** be placed in the Fiktionsbescheinigung:

- [Traveling with Erlaubnisfiktion [Fiktionsbescheinigung] - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169855/95267)

There you will find:

> **Article 1 Paragraph 2 of Regulation (EC) Number 539/2001**
>
> > Nationals of third countries on the list in Annex II shall be exempt from the requirement set out in paragraph 1 for stays of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period.

listed in the exceptions.